# user=User.objects.get_or_create(first_name=fk_first_name,last_name=fk_last_name,email=fk_email)[0] why [0] is used

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

in this python code which is creating fake name with email :

```
from faker import Faker
from .models import User
fk=Faker()

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        fk_name=fk.name().split()
        fk_first_name=fk_name[0]
        fk_last_name=fk_last[1]
        fk_email=fk.email()

        user=User.objects.get_or_create(first_name=fk_first_name,last_name=fk_last_name,email=fk_email)[0]
if __name__=='__main__':
    inp=int(input("please enter the integer value for population"))
    print('Populating ......................')
    populate(inp)
    print("population is done \n")
```

in this user=User.objects.get_or_create(first_name=fk_first_name,last_name=fk_last_name,email=fk_email)[0] why [0] is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [**`.get_or_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns a 2-tuple with as first element the object (retrieved or created), and as second element a boolean that is `True` if the object was created, and `False` if it was not. This is specified in the documentation:

> Returns a **tuple of `(object, created)`**, where `object` is the retrieved or created object and `created` is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

This thus means that if we write:

```
some_obj = MyModel.objects.get_or_created()
```

then `some_obj` is a 2-tuple, not the `MyModel` object. We can use subscripting to access the first element, for example:

```
some_obj = MyModel.objects.get_or_created()[0]
```

It is common however to use iterable unpacking, and write this as:

```
some_obj, __ = MyModel.objects.get_or_created()
```

here we thus store the object in `some_obj`, and we use another variable `__` to store the boolean into if we do not care if the object is created or not.